# First order differential equation problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-forms, differential

Suppose we have $$ \frac{dy}{dx} +f(x)y = r(x) $$ and it has two solutions $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ then how to prove that solution of differential equation  $$ \frac{dy}{dx} +f(x)y = 2r(x) $$
Will be $y_1(x)+y_2(x)$ ?
I think given differential equations is linear first order equation so its solution will be 
$$y.e^{\int f(x)dx} = \int r. e^{\int f(x)dx}dx $$ now do I establish two solution as $y_1$ and $y_2$ out of this equation?

Comment: Did you try simply substituting $y_1+y_2$, and then verifying that it satisfies the equation?

Comment: Also, $ay_1+by_2$ will solve the equation as long as $a+b=2$.

Comment: @Aahz I am not allowed to do that way , i need to formally prove it using given equation to arrive at this result

Comment: Well, you can only prove that $y_1+y_2$ is **a** solution, not **the** solution, as there are many solutions.

Comment: Yes , of course one of the solutions :)

Comment: is $y(x)=f(x)$ given here?

Comment: Nope , we don't know about that but i think it should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is not just placing the solution in and determining that it satisfies..however I will proceed!

$$
y_1'' + f(x)y_1' = r(x)\\
y_2'' + f(x)y_2' = r(x).
$$
adding the two equations together we obtain
$$
y_1'' + y_2'' + f(x)y_1' + f(x)y_2' = 2r(x)\\
\left(y_1 + y_2\right)'' + f(x)\left(y_1'+y_2'\right) = \\
\left(y_1 + y_2\right)'' + f(x)\left(y_1+y_2\right)' = 2r(x).
$$
so we find (as not surprising) the solution $y_1 + y_2$ satisfies the equation.

If this is not the kind of process you would like to follow then I can try to improve.